# Gitlab Community Edition "Error: refs/keep-around/*long number/character string* does not point to a valid object!"

Tags: git, gitlab

new to Git in general so thanks in advance for your patience!

Using a self-hosted server. After creating a new branch from master using the website at the local IP address for an issue , I ran git fetch intending to switch to that branch and get to work. I was greeted with the following error:

```
error: refs/keep-around/6140333099caa1bc63d35c69b216c93683058cad does not point to a valid object!
```

If I cd into the .git/refs directory I don’t see a keep-around directory. The error occurs any time I run a command it seems, but does not stop the command from completing. Still, I’m left worried that something is wrong with the repo so I’d like to resolve it if possible.

git fsck --full returns the following and that's it:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (4959/4959), done.
```

I also tried deleting the repo and cloning again, which also did not resolve the issue.

A bit of googling has gotten me nowhere, so any assistance in resolving this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The ref is probably in `.git/packed-refs`. The plumbing command `git for-each-ref` will show it. `refs/keep-around/` is not a standard Git reference name-space: some person must have created this ref with some specific intent. Find out who did it and why, and see what *they* want to do about this problem. If no one claims ownership, you can delete the name using `git update-ref -d`, which will make the problem go away, but won't do anything nice for whoever *wanted* this strange ref.

Comment: @torek when I use git for-each-ref I still don't see any mention of this particular ref. The only things that come up are refs/heads/master and commits to refs/remotes/origin. The timing on this is also odd, since this error is very new and no one else in our small project was around to make changes except me (which has me thinking I messed something up). My predecessor is long gone and my boss was out of the office this week. If the boss doesn't know what it is when he calls me later today, I'll give update-ref -d a go to resolve it. Thank you!

Comment: @torek I got the go-ahead to try git update-ref -d refs/keep-around and...it runs, and returns nothing. I then tried git fetch and I still get the error:


`error: refs/keep-around/6140333099caa1bc63d35c69b216c93683058cad does not point to a valid object!
remote: error: refs/keep-around/6140333099caa1bc63d35c69b216c93683058cad does not point to a valid object!`

Comment: Maybe the `refs/keep-around/...` is in *your* repository, rather than the one on GitLab...?  Use `git for-each-ref` to view all the refs in each repository (or see the `for-each-ref` documentation to see how to view subsets).

Answer (score 0):

We ended up resolving the error after looking around the remote server a bit. We accessed the remote server with SSH, went to home/git-data/repositories/[groupName]/[repoName.git]/refs/keep-around and deleted the specific ref that matched the error. Boss doesn't know where these keep-around refs came from, but the error is gone and nothing else is broken thus far (we keep backups of the server that we could have gone back to just in case it did break something) so I guess this is solved. Thanks for assisting regardless!